# java: How to print self referential data in PrimeFaces tree view controll?

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, primefaces

I have category table 
Category(id,category name,parent_id)
In category table parent_id->related with id
So how to print such type of data in tree view controll of primeface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

public TreeNode createTree(int a, TreeNode rootNode) {

```
    TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(a, rootNode);

    Collection<Catagary> c=port.viewCategoryByPId(a);

    for (Catagary tt : c) {

        TreeNode newNode2 = createTree(tt.getId(), newNode);
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TreeNode newNode = new DefaultTreeNode(a, rootNode);
Collection<Catagary> c=port.viewCategoryByPId(a);
for (Catagary cat : c) 
{
    TreeNode newNode2 = createTree(cat.getId(), newNode);
}

write this code.
```

Comment: Add some comment to clarify what's your code actually do.